# Elasticsearch DateTime Range Query Inconsistent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, searchkick

I am trying to use elastic search with searchkick in a rails application to query a date range. I have tried many things but this is the current state. I am trying to search by `last_contacted` which is stored on the schema as a `datetime`.

My `searchdata` function looks as follows

```
 def search_data_attributes
{
  tag: tags.map { |t| t.name.downcase },
  trait: person_traits.map { |pt| format('%s:%s', traits.find(pt.trait_id).name.downcase, pt.value.downcase) },
  question: questions.map(&:id),
  answer: answers.map { |a| a.value.downcase },
  last_participated: last_participation_date.to_s,
  signup_at: signup_at.to_s,
  full_name: full_name,
  last_contacted: last_contacted
}
```

end

I have tried making `last_contacted.to_s`.

My search query looks as follows

```
{
    query: {
        range: {
            last_contacted: {
              gte: "2018-09-15",
              lte: "now"
            }
          }
    }
  }
```

I have tried use date math such as `now-20d` but that returns zero results. If I have no `gte` limit searching by `now` in `lte` returns all results as expected but any change I make to `gte` returns zero results using datemath.

I appreciate any help and would be happy to answer questions.

Thank You.

Comment: Have you checked some entries? That would happen if last_contacted is null for all entries. Also, check the mapping on the index https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-mapping.html - what is the mapping for last_contacted?

Comment: May you please post your mapping and a couple of example documents?

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert the format of the date:

```
{
  query: {
    range: {
        last_contacted: {
          gte: "01/01/2012",
          lte: "now",
          format: "dd/MM/yyyy"
        }
      }
   }
}
```